# Can I extract all the route keys of react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I'm trying to make a key map for all the screens.
For that, I need to extract all the keys from navigation container of `react-navigation`.

For example,

```
const result = {
   MainScreen: 'Main-p-u9s_rA3z5HCT-KHyDua',
   IndexScreen: 'Index-97mYyg2-P5Kb_wGY4E1ke',
   <RouteName>: <RouteKey>
   ...
}
```

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`getRootState`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/#getrootstate).

> The getRootState method returns a navigation state object containing the navigation states for all navigators in the navigation tree

```
export const navigationRef = React.createRef();

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const navigationState = navigationRef.current?.getRootState();

    const result = {};
    navigationState.routes.forEach(route => {
      result[route.name] = route.key;
    });
    console.log(result);
  }, [navigationRef]);
  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Screen3" component={Screen3} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

`console.log(result)` in the code above returns something like this:

> {"Screen1": "Screen1-AVVWEcCJjDeVeO3fu4tgb", "Screen2": "Screen2-nXoQ6xsdjKxoB4hbeXNou", "Screen3": "Screen3-FuFi77tfvex2QXZfin86s"}

Keep in mind when using `getRootState`:

> ...the returned state object will be undefined if there are no navigators currently rendered.

Also look at [the navigation state reference](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-state/).

Comment: If there is a screen that hasn't been rendered yet, this mean it may not be on rootState?

Comment: Yes if a navigator hasn't rendered it won't show up in the navigation state object. This also applies for nested navigators. If you have nested navigators you also probably need more loops to get those routes in the `result` object or you could get the navigation state of a navigator when it renders without using `getRootState`. Either way I don't think it's possible to get everything at once.